# PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: permission_denied (Access denied.) Connecting Spring Boot To Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot

I am using `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0.` 
I have set following rules in firebase.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Still I am getting

> PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: permission_denied
>   (Access denied.).

Comment: Adding .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(null) resolved my issue.

Comment: FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setServiceAccount(resource)
                    .setDatabaseUrl(Constant.FIREVASE_DATABASE_URL)
                    .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(null)
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);